# How do I give my facebook app access to post to my facebook page?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-oauth

I have a windows service that tries to post to my facebook page.  The following returns an access token but when I go to post the message, it throws this exception?  How can I tell my facebook page that this application can post to it?

> (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the
>   application to perform this action

Here is the main call:

```
string accessToken = FacebookPoster.GetAccessToken("************", "***************");
FacebookPoster.PostMessage(accessToken, "My message");
```

Here is my FacebookPoster class:

```
public class FacebookPoster
{
    private const string AuthenticationUrlFormat =
        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream";


    public static string GetAccessToken(string apiId, string apiSecret)
    {
        string accessToken = string.Empty;
        string url = string.Format(AuthenticationUrlFormat, apiId, apiSecret);

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responseString);

            accessToken = query["access_token"];
        }

        if (accessToken.Trim().Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("There is no Access Token");

        // this returns an access token
        return accessToken;
    }

    public static void PostMessage(string accessToken, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

            dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
            messagePost.access_token = accessToken;

            //messagePost.picture = "[A_PICTURE]";
            //messagePost.link = "[SOME_LINK]";
            //messagePost.name = "[SOME_NAME]";
            //messagePost.caption = "my caption"; 
            messagePost.message = message;
            //messagePost.description = "my description";


            // this call throws the exception:
            //  (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
            var result = facebookClient.Post("/643028262411859/feed", messagePost);
        }
        catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
        {
             //handle something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             //handle something else
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to do this

Go here and click the Graph Explorer to generate an access token

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/

then this code will create the post:

```
public static void PostMessage(string accessToken, string message)
{
    try
    {
        FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        dynamic getAccess = new ExpandoObject();
        getAccess.access_token = accessToken;

        dynamic accessResult = facebookClient.Get("/{your facebook userID}/accounts", getAccess);

        foreach (dynamic j in accessResult.data)
        {
            if (j.name == "{Name of your facebook page}")
            {
                accessToken = j.access_token;
            }
        }

        dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
        messagePost.access_token = accessToken;

        //messagePost.picture = "";
        //messagePost.link = "[SOME_LINK]";
        //messagePost.name = "[SOME_NAME]";
        //messagePost.caption = "";

        messagePost.message = message;

        messagePost.url = "{url}";            

        // this will make a photo post
        var result = facebookClient.Post("/{your page name}/photos", messagePost);

        // this will make a regular post to your feed
        facebookClient.Post("/{your page name}/feed", messagePost);
    }
    catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
    {
         //handle something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         //handle something else
    }
}
```